# Elasticsearch keyword with spaces in term query on keyword

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mapping:

```
{
  "events": {
    "mappings": {
      "event": {
        "Type of Event": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the following data inside the index

```
{
  "Type of Event": "Orientation Session"
},
{
  "Type of Event": "Orientation Tutorial"
}
```

I am trying to match only those with `Type of Event == "Orientation Session"`.

I'm trying the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "Type of Event.keyword": "Orientation Session"
    }
  }
}
```

but it doesn't match anything. It does, however, work if there are no spaces in the string. I can't use `match` query here, as it would match both events.

What am I doing wrong? I've seen a lot of discussion on spaces in term queries, but none about using `keyword`. They all are specific to elasticsearch 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your mapping is wrong, you're missing the `properties` keyword.

If you try to create your index with the mapping you gave, you should get the following error:

```
unknown setting [index.events.mappings.event.Type of Event.fields.keyword.ignore_above] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
```

So you need to use the following mapping instead, and it will work:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "event": {
      "properties": {             <--- this was missing
        "Type of Event": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```